# I don't know how to add models onto the method I'm using

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I'm very new to Springboot and I just wish I knew if there was a way to correct the flow between a class, the interface that implements it and the controller. I'm currently using Thymeleaf so I would like to send the result method into a Model type and print it somewhere on the HTML. This is my current setup:

```
public class CalculosServiceImpl implements CalculosService{

    @Override
        public String esPrimo(int number) {
        String respuesta="No es primo";
        respuesta = "No es primo";
        for (int x = 2; x <= Math.sqrt(number); x++) {
            if (number % x == 0) {
                respuesta = "Es primo";
            }
        }
        return "respuesta";
        
    }
```

```
public interface CalculosService {
    
    String esPrimo(int number);
}
```

```
    @GetMapping("/calculos/primo")
    public String esPrimo(@RequestParam("number") int number, Model model){
        calculosService.esPrimo(number);
        model.addAttribute("number", number);
        return "index"; 
    }
```

I tried to locate the return Model on multiple parts of my code. I tried to turn the result of "number" into a Model type and I also tried to locate it on multiple parts of my code without success. What would be the correct flow for it?